# Mutual exchange of data between wordpress blog and PHP site using Rest Api?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

I am developing two simple sites using wordpress and other using PHP i want to exchange data between these two mutually using Rest.

I must be able to post data into or get data from wordpress site from site build based on PHP.

I must be able to post data into or get data from PHP based site from my wordpress site

these both are on localhost is there any plugin, documentation or resource for this to be performed.

Any suggestions will help me thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the Wordpress API - it should allow You to insert or get the desired data. This should be enough for both the sites - just You would need to implement such an API on the other (not Wordpress) site that would be capable of calling Wordpress API methods and retrieve or send the data...

Comment: i Used json api to get and post data but from wordpress to mysite but how to post and get from php site to wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Could do with some more information to be more helpful, for example if you are developing the two sites, why not do them both in Wordpress? Is the standard PHP site an existing project you are taking over? Is the code completely written from scratch or does it use a framework?

In the meantime I would suggest looking into a Framework, for example I use Zend Framework, and although I haven't used it specficially it does have REST client and server classes

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.rest.server.html

Looks quite nice

```
/**
* Say Hello
*
* @param string $who
* @param string $when
* @return string
*/
function sayHello($who, $when)
{
    return "Hello $who, Good $when";
}

$server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
$server->addFunction('sayHello');
$server->handle();
```